# Did I compile with OpenMPI or MPICH?

Tags: openmpi, mpich

I have an executable on my Linux box which I know has been compiled either with `OpenMPI` or `MPICH` libraries.

Question: how to determine which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following diagnostic procedure assumes that MPICH/MPICH2 and Open MPI are
the only possible MPI implementations that you may have linked with.  Other
(especially commercial) MPI implementations do exist and may have different
library names and/or library symbols.

First determine if you linked dynamically:

```
% ldd my_executable
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff972c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1f3c6cd000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1f3c4c5000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1f3c2a7000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1f3bf21000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1f3c969000)
```

If you see `libmpich.so` in that list, then you have dynamically linked to
MPICH (or MPICH2).  If you see `libmpi.so` then you have linked with Open MPI.

If neither is present, then you probably just linked statically.  In that case
we need to examine the binary to look for distinguishing symbols:

```
% ( nm my_executable | grep MPIR_Free_contextid >/dev/null ) && echo "MPICH"
% ( nm my_executable | grep ompi_comm_set_name >/dev/null ) && echo "Open MPI"
```

Answer (score 1):

Open MPI applications react to MCA parameters, that can be passed in environment variables. Just run the executable in singleton mode (i.e. without `mpirun`/`mpiexec`) with something like `sysinfo_base_verbose` set to 30:

```
$ OMPI_MCA_sysinfo_base_verbose=30 ./program
```

If you get an output like:

```
[hostname:pid] mca: base: components_open: Looking for sysinfo components
```

then this is more than robust indication that the executable uses Open MPI.