# How do I tell what version of MPICH or OpenMPI that I have?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

I am an extremely novice user of MPI and its relatives.  On the node that I have access to at my institution, MPI is installed, but I would like to know what version I have.

[From this old question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356765/how-do-i-check-the-version-of-mpich) an answer suggests trying:

```
mpiexec --version
```

But when I try this, I get this error message:

```
invalid "local" arg: --version

usage:
mpiexec [-h or -help or --help]    # get this message
mpiexec -file filename             # (or -f) filename contains XML job description
mpiexec [global args] [local args] executable [args]
```

Having said this, I am not completely sure that I have MPICH.  I may instead have OpenMPI.  But I do, I think, have MPICH because I ran `ldd` on my program, and the output included references to `libmpich.so`, which [an answer to this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619218/did-i-compile-with-openmpi-or-mpich) says is indicative of MPICH rather than OpenMPI.

Do you have any ideas of how I can extract the version of MPI that I am using?

## Addendum

Another answer on [that old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356765/how-do-i-check-the-version-of-mpich) says to try:

```
mpicc -v
```

I have tried this, and I get this output:

```
mpicc for MPICH2 version 1.2.1p1
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
```

So I guess I have **MPICH2 version 1.2.1p1**.  But can I know from this that for sure that **MPICH2 version 1.2.1p1** is currently installed?  Or could it be that `mpicc` was configured with **MPICH2 version 1.2.1p1** and now a different version of MPI could be installed?

Comment: If you happen to have Open MPI, then the following command will give you the OMPI version number: `ompi_info | grep Ident`

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have installed `MPICH2 1.2.1p1` and it's your default `mpicc`. If you install another MPI distribution (e.g. Open MPI), then you need to adjust the paths such that you can use the newly installed one.